# Issue using $.ajax in IE when dynamically adding items to a model's collection

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer

I hope I can phrase this question appropriately. I was reviewing various articles on how to dynamically add items to a model's collection and still retain the binding. Mainly I was looking at the two following:

**MVC Series Part 1: Dynamically Adding Items Part 1:**
http://blogs.interknowlogy.com/2014/08/01/mvc-series-part-1-dynamically-adding-items-part-1/

**Model Binding to a List:**
http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/

In my scenario I have a simple input of type button which invokes a jQuery ajax call to a controller action that returns a `PartialView`, which I then simply append to my DOM. In this `PartialView` I call the HtmlHelper extension function `Html.BeginCollectionItem` (based on the demo in first article) that simply inserts the necessary hidden fields and updates the HTML prefixes appropriately. The `PartialView` cshtml file looks like so:

```
@using Project.MyExtensions
@model Models.MyModel

<div class="item">
@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("CollectionItem"))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)
    <div class="row">
        <div class="six columns">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, "Name")
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, null, new {@class = "u-full-width"})
        </div>

        <div class="six columns">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.HostName, "Hostname")
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.HostName, null, new {@class = "u-full-width"})
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description, "Description")
        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Description, new {@class = "u-full-width"})
    </div>

    <div class="close">Remove</div>
}
</div>
```

In Mozilla this works fine and I was able to dynamically add items to the model's collection as expected. Although on Internet Explorer (IE) I noticed something odd.

If I made the ajax call via the following jQuery function, IE would call my HtmlHelper extension method the FIRST time only and after that it's never invoked again:

```
$("#add-newItem").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("NewItem", "MyController")',
        dataType: 'html',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#item-list').prepend(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Although if I use the `@Ajax.ActionLink`helper function IE works as expected and my HtmlHelper extension method in `PartialView` seems to be invoked every time as expected:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Add New Item", "NewItem", new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "GET",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertBefore,
    UpdateTargetId = "item-list"
})
```

In Mozilla both ways work as expected but in IE I only see the expected results via the 2nd method. Could someone explain what might be the difference here?

**Update:** I noticed that in IE I was able to get the HtmlHelper extension method invoked consistently (via the $.ajax method) if I had the "Inspect Element" debugger tool open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get this to work in IE by modifying my $.ajax call to specify `cache: false`. This seems to indicate that the browser caching affects the created Partials in IE (something which I did not expect to be the case). It also explains why having the debugger being open would cause the $.ajax call to behave differently since I believe that forces the caching to be disabled.

If anyone has any further information please comment below but for now I'll close the question.